# Limit BACS "on-hold" orders to only one by customer in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, payment-method

We offer BACS (bank transfer) as a payment method on our WooCommerce store.
If someone uses that method:

- stock is reduced for that product
- order is on-hold for 48 hrs

The issue we are having is that some people take advantage of that and they use that method to reserve products. They wait for the order to be cancelled and then do it again, and whenever they have some money, they actually pay for it.

As a secondhand store, of course that is not desired behavior.

**Is there a way to limit the number of BACS orders with "on hold" status to just only one?**

That way, if you want to pay with BACS and your email already has one order pending, it will return an error and you won't be able to finish checkout.
Of course people can use different emails, but it starts to get complex.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - *Added guest using the billing email.*

The following very simple hooked function will check if the current customer has any "on-hold" BACS order and if it's the case, it will display an error message avoiding checkout, if the current order is using BACS payment method:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'action_wc_checkout_process_callback' );
function action_wc_checkout_process_callback() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Get customer "on-hold" orders
        $orders = (array) wc_get_orders(['limit' => - 1, 'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
            'status' => 'on-hold', 'return' => 'ids']);
    } elseif ( isset($_POST['billing_email']) && ! empty($_POST['billing_email']) ) {
        // Get customer "on-hold" orders
        $orders = (array) wc_get_orders(['limit' => - 1, 'customer' => sanitize_email($_POST['billing_email']), 'status' => 'on-hold', 'return' => 'ids']);
    }

    // Check if the current customer has any "on-hold" BACS order and if current order is using BACS as payment method
    if ( isset($orders) && count($orders) > 0 && isset($_POST['payment_method']) && $_POST['payment_method'] === 'bacs' ) {
        // Display an error notice (and avoid checkout)
        wc_add_notice( __( "You have already one order awaiting payment and you can have only one at the time.", "woocommerce" ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: You're on fire man. It's the second question you help me with, and you completely nailed it. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: hi @LoicTheAztec I think there might be something wrong with the code. On some cases, where customers have orders on status completed or cancelled, the error is still returned. is this only working when users are logged in, or it also works as guests? i think this might be related to users as guests, but I'm not sure how that case should be covered. thanks!

Comment: to be more accurate, the code is not working on guests. currently the code gets the customer id, but i'm not sure how to get the billing email whenever the user is not logged in. that should be the expected behavior whenever a guest user tries to purchase.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it affected you once the question was answered, I thought it was the proper way to put the info here on Stack Overflow. Will make sure to don't do it again. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: @SantiagoValdés You can do that when the answer has a bug and it's author doesn't solve it… But in your case you should first notify the author of the answer and if it doesn't handle the additional 'guests' request, you can ask a new question providing a link to the related answer code. Always  give some time to the author of the answer, to let it solve the problem, so wait some time before unaccepting an answer. I have updated my code again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I don't have much experience in SO, only a couple questions in the past (and mostly unanswered), so appreciate taking the time to explain. Will definitely do that in case I ask something in the future. Appreciate your help again, amazing work!